# How do you get the administrator effect off your computer so nothing is bloced on your computer

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace, google-docs, google-forms

Is there anyway to remove the administrator or like overpower it
I have look everywhere but it seems like there is no possible way

Answer (score 0):

Programs cannot make changes to your computer without administrative rights, for security reasons. The administrative privilege prevents applications or scripts from adjusting your computer without your consent, because those adjustments could potentially put malware on your computer.

In addition, the right for a program to make changes often requires administrative privileges, just because so many settings on your computer have the potential to cause a problem, if the user is inexperienced. The admin rights therefore are also intended to prevent inexperienced users from causing problems on the system.